# How do I keep a grouped column from moving down or disappearing when using gt?

Tags: r, shiny, gt

I'm using the gt and gtExtras packages to create a grouped table where the minimum and maximum values for each group is highlighted. The end goal is to make it interactive and put it in a Shiny app. The challenge I'm facing is that the column I'm grouping on disappears when I make the table interactive and it is moved down a level when it's static. Is there a way to fix this? I've tried everything I can think of to no avail.

```
    df <- structure(list(company = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
                     account_num = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L), sales = c(173L, 
                                                                            126L, 142L, 107L, 151L, 123L, 198L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                            "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))


df |> 
  gt(groupname_col = "company") %>%
  # tab_stubhead(label = "company") |>
  # gt(rowname_col = "company") %>%
  
  gtExtras::tab_style_by_grp(
    column = sales,
    fn     = min,
    cell_fill("orange")) %>%
  gtExtras::tab_style_by_grp(
    column = sales,
    fn     = max,
    cell_fill("lightblue")) %>%
  opt_interactive(active = TRUE,
                  use_search = F,
                  use_filters = TRUE
  )
```

What I'm getting is this when it's interactive:
[image]

And this when it is static:
[image]

The goal is something like this but with the appropriate cells colored like above:
[image]

Is there a way to keep the structure of the table and still color the correct cells by group? I'd prefer to have the table interactive with the possibility to search, filter and sort but can live without if I must. I really like the gt package and I'm hoping it can do the trick.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the best of my knowledge, you may solve your 'static problem' by adding

```
tab_stubhead(label = "company") %>%
tab_options(row_group.as_column = T)
```

where "company" is a string, not a variable name of your dataframe. The resulting output will be as follows:

[image]

I think it might serve as a stopgap. Hope someone finds a better solution than mine.

Comment: I ended up just duplicating the company column and that solved it in a way. But I'd be surprised if there isn't a built in way to do it in gt...

Comment: Yep, I thought about creating another column, but ended up looking for an integrated option in the package; unfortunately I didn't find out another way of doing it in the static form. Regarding the interactive one I think the final form of the table may not be an expected result - which would be understandable given that the interactive form is recently new.